# How to insert a shape in a powerpoint slide using OpenXML

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

This question could seem rather basic, but how do I insert a shape (i. e. a rectangle) in a slide using OpenXML in c#?

I've searched around and all I see is "create a slide with the shape and use the SDK Productivity Tool to reflect the code. That's not really helpful :(

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After hitting my head against the wall for a while, finally I took the advice, created a slide with the shape and used the tool to reflect the code. So for next generations, here is a brief explanation of how to do it by hand.

Firts of all you have to know is that a shape is inserted into a ShapeTree, which is part of a CommonSlideData:

```
Slide s = GetDesiredSlide(); // Get the slide where you want to insert the shape.
s.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Append(GenerateShape());
```

Second you should know is that a shape must contain at least 4 childs that describe its behavior:

- A ShapeStyle object
- A ShapeProperties object
- A TextBody object
- A NonVisualShapeProperties

In the sample code bellow I am using the following namespaces and variables:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Presentation;
using D = DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Drawing;

D.ShapeTypeValues shapeType; // Any of the built-in shapes (ellipse, rectangle, etc)
string rgbColorHex; // Hexadecimal RGB color code to fill the shape.
long x; // Represents the shape x position in 1/36000 cm.
long y; // Represents the shape y position in 1/36000 cm.
long width; // Shapw width in in 1/36000 cm.
long heigth;// Shapw heigth in in 1/36000 cm.
```

**ShapeStyle Object**

The shape style object describes general shape style attributes like the borders, the fill style, the text font and the visual effect (shadows, and other)

```
ShapeStyle shapeStyle1 = new ShapeStyle();

D.LineReference lineReference1 = new D.LineReference() { Index = (UInt32Value)2U };

D.SchemeColor schemeColor2 = new D.SchemeColor() { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.Accent1 };
D.Shade shade1 = new D.Shade() { Val = 50000 };

schemeColor2.Append(shade1);

lineReference1.Append(schemeColor2);

D.FillReference fillReference1 = new D.FillReference() { Index = (UInt32Value)1U };
D.SchemeColor schemeColor3 = new D.SchemeColor() { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.Accent1 };

fillReference1.Append(schemeColor3);

D.EffectReference effectReference1 = new D.EffectReference() { Index = (UInt32Value)0U };
D.SchemeColor schemeColor4 = new D.SchemeColor() { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.Accent1 };

effectReference1.Append(schemeColor4);

D.FontReference fontReference1 = new D.FontReference() { Index = D.FontCollectionIndexValues.Minor };
D.SchemeColor schemeColor5 = new D.SchemeColor() { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.Light1 };

fontReference1.Append(schemeColor5);

shapeStyle1.Append(lineReference1);
shapeStyle1.Append(fillReference1);
shapeStyle1.Append(effectReference1);
shapeStyle1.Append(fontReference1);
```

**ShapeProperties**

Define shape's visual Properties like Fill method (solid, gradient, etc.) Geometry (size, location, flipping, rotarion) Fill and Outline.

```
ShapeProperties shapeProperties1 = new ShapeProperties();

D.Transform2D transform2D1 = new D.Transform2D();
D.Offset offset1 = new D.Offset() { X = x, Y = y };
D.Extents extents1 = new D.Extents() { Cx = width, Cy = heigth };

transform2D1.Append(offset1);
transform2D1.Append(extents1);

D.PresetGeometry presetGeometry1 = new D.PresetGeometry() { Preset = shapeType };
D.AdjustValueList adjustValueList1 = new D.AdjustValueList();

presetGeometry1.Append(adjustValueList1);

D.SolidFill solidFill1 = new D.SolidFill();
D.RgbColorModelHex rgbColorModelHex1 = new D.RgbColorModelHex() { Val = rgbColorHex };

solidFill1.Append(rgbColorModelHex1);

D.Outline outline1 = new D.Outline() { Width = 12700 };

D.SolidFill solidFill2 = new D.SolidFill();
D.SchemeColor schemeColor1 = new D.SchemeColor() { Val = D.SchemeColorValues.Text1 };

solidFill2.Append(schemeColor1);

outline1.Append(solidFill2);

shapeProperties1.Append(transform2D1);
shapeProperties1.Append(presetGeometry1);
shapeProperties1.Append(solidFill1);
shapeProperties1.Append(outline1);
```

**TextBody**

Defines the textbox attributes like number of columns, alignment, anchoring, etc.

```
TextBody textBody1 = new TextBody();
D.BodyProperties bodyProperties1 = new D.BodyProperties() { RightToLeftColumns = false, Anchor = D.TextAnchoringTypeValues.Center };
D.ListStyle listStyle1 = new D.ListStyle();

D.Paragraph paragraph1 = new D.Paragraph();
D.ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties1 = new D.ParagraphProperties() { Alignment = D.TextAlignmentTypeValues.Center };
D.EndParagraphRunProperties endParagraphRunProperties1 = new D.EndParagraphRunProperties() { Language = "es-ES" };

paragraph1.Append(paragraphProperties1);
paragraph1.Append(endParagraphRunProperties1);

textBody1.Append(bodyProperties1);
textBody1.Append(listStyle1);
textBody1.Append(paragraph1);
```

**NonVisualShapeProperties**

Define non visual properties like the Name and the Id.

```
NonVisualShapeProperties nonVisualShapeProperties1 = new NonVisualShapeProperties();
NonVisualDrawingProperties nonVisualDrawingProperties1 = new NonVisualDrawingProperties() { Id = (UInt32Value)4U, Name = "1 Shape Name" };
NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties1 = new NonVisualShapeDrawingProperties();
ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties1 = new ApplicationNonVisualDrawingProperties();

nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(nonVisualDrawingProperties1);
nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(nonVisualShapeDrawingProperties1);
nonVisualShapeProperties1.Append(applicationNonVisualDrawingProperties1);
```

**Putting all together**

Finally you have to create the shape object and append these properties to it:

```
Shape shape1 = new Shape();
shape1.Append(nonVisualShapeProperties1);
shape1.Append(shapeProperties1);
shape1.Append(shapeStyle1);
shape1.Append(textBody1);
```

And then, add the shape to the slide's shape tree:

```
s.CommonSlideData.ShapeTree.Append(shape1);
```

Comment: Good job dude! This seems to be a good start. The examples and explanations of the msdn side are low and I have like thousand questions about the mechanics. But i think everyone need to find that out on his own way.